# How to detect Ipad useragent on safari browser

Tags: safari, user-agent

when I use ipad on chrome the useragent is

> Mozila/5.0(**iPad**; CPU OS 9_3_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1
>   (KHTML,like Gecko) CruiOS/57.0.2987.137 Mobile/13G36 ....

but ipad on safari is

> (**Macintosh**; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15

And MacOS useragent is

> Safari: Mozilla/5.0 (***Macintosh***; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100
>   Safari/537.36

Problem : Since on iPadOS User Agent on Safari is same as on MacOS notebook following https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119186

and I this issue of Mobile_Detect php library https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/issues/795

Comment: Yes, same issue, user agent on iPad(iOS14) is useless when trying to detect mobile Safari browser. it is reported as mac os (not as ipad anymore) Safari. Same thing is happening with Firefox on iPad. I can only detect Chrome b/c it shows up as Mobile Chrome.

Comment: This sounds like a very stupid move to make iPad pretend they are Mac. Especially when so many API differs between Mac and iPad... I'm curious to know why Apple thought that it would be a great idea...

Answer (score 14):

To detect iPads, try this:

```
let isIpad = /Macintosh/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && navigator.maxTouchPoints && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1;
```